# Unity Remote 5 - Doesn't work with any version of Unity for me

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-remote

I've read over 50 threads about Unity Remote on this website, however, nothing has resolved my issue. I've tried downloading every version from 2018-2019 but the Unity remote doesn't work at all for me.
I've followed many tutorials so i have went to Edit>>Project Settings>>Editor and I have selected Use Any Android Device. I've tried different variations of plugging in my device, closing unity/opening unity, and different variations of opening Unity remote. Nothing seems to work so I'm thinking this might be an issue with my computer. How can I find this out? 
Most importantly, if someone could break down the precise order in which they use to use Unity remote, that might be helpful as well.At this point I'm open to all advice and willing to try everything until something works. I really need this to work!

I'm using Unity 2018.3.9f1 and my phone is ZTE Blade.

Question summary:

1. How to detect if USB drivers are the issue? How to resolve?
2. What is the precise ordered steps in which to use Unity Remote 5?

Comment: Are you sure ADB detects your device? (`adb devices`) personally, I always : close Unity, start Unity Remote, start Unity, play game.

Comment: @Hellium - How do I check or test if ADB is detecting my device? Trust me, I've tried closing, starting remote, starting unity, click play, however, it hasn't worked for me. Sad, really! Game testing by creating build after build is getting very old, very quick! I really need unity remote in my life lol I wanna try your ADB theory, for this, I've never attempted. Perhaps the solution resides here?

Comment: You have to find the ADB executable (find Android SDK, then subfolder sdk/platform-tools if I remember correctly. I advise you to put this folder in your PATH). Then, run the command `adb devices` in the console once your device is plugged in.

Comment: @Hellium That worked for me and I'd accept the answer if you care to submit one. Thanks!